# Excepting - not excepting

Tags: grammar

I have found this definition on the usage of "excepting"

**The use of excepting is considered by many people to be acceptable only after not, only, or without.**

Do you agree? Could you give some examples using **not, only, without**. What about - not excepting? Is it also used after **not, only, without** only? Are "excepting" and "except that" synonyms?

Comment: Wouldn't the use of _excepting_ after _not_ be exactly, and _all_ the use of _not excepting_???

Comment: I don't know if I'm missing something, but I think the most frequent use of *excepting* is at the beginning of sentences.

Comment: @Damkerng: You must be missing something! :) Most people rarely use *[not] excepting* at all (and as OP's source implies, even less people use it in non-negated contexts). When it *is* used, you can usually put the *not excepting* clause either before or after the main clause, but sometimes one sequence works much better than the other. And unless I'm much mistaken, it's usually the *main* clause that works better in the first position (because it tells you the context, which you need to know in order to understand why someone/something might *not* be excepted).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks a lot! Reading your answer, I can see why they wrote that now; though I think "The use of excepting is considered by *some* people to be acceptable only after not, only, or without" *might* be more realistic. (By the way, I guess your 3a could sound better if it were "All men are fallible, FumbleFingers excepted." Not absolutely sure. Just my intuition.) Interestingly, according to snailplane's results, *excepting* is most common after a comma, a parenthesis, a period, an em-dash, then after *not*, *always*, and *and*. In any case, it's pretty for me to use *excepting*.

Comment: @Damkerng: Re commas etc. - it's a parenthetical clause. Note [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=without+excepting%2Cnot+excepting%2Cnot+excepted&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwithout%20excepting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20excepting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20excepted%3B%2Cc0), showing just how far even the supposedly acceptable *negated* forms have fallen into disuse. For most, this was never a "rule taught in school", so they probably have no real opinion (but they'd be unlikely to actually produce *any* version themselves).

Answer (score 3):

I think "acceptable/unacceptable" is maybe putting it a bit strong, but note this (slightly paraphrased) entry from Fowler's [*Dictionary of Modern English Usage*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22either%20not%20excepting%20before%20the%20noun%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)...

> ***excepting*** as a preposition has **one normal use**
>   When a possible exception is to be mentioned as ***not made***, the form used [instead of *not except*] is either *not excepting* (before the noun) or *not excepted* (after the noun).

That's my emphasis on *not made* above, but clearly Fowler thinks *excepting* as a preposition is normally only used in negated contexts, and I would tend to agree. The fact of the matter is the verb ***to except*** is a pretty rare/dated usage apart from the two "set phrases" *not excepting* and *not excepted* as discussed above (where the verb form has effectively taken on the role of "preposition").

---

Borrowing from and extending Fowler's examples in that link, consider...

> 1: All men are fallible, not excepting the Pope
>    2: All men are fallible, the Pope not excepted
>    3: ??All men are fallible, excepting FumbleFingers
>
> 1a: Not excepting the Pope, all men are fallible
>    2a: The Pope not excepted, all men are fallible
>    3a: ??Excepted FumbleFingers, all men are fallible

I've included the second set to show it doesn't really make any difference if the supplementary clause appears before or after the main statement. Obviously I'd like to say 3/3a are "acceptable", but they're not really. Any "normal" native speaker (assuming he accepted my infallibility) would say...

> 3b: All men are fallible, **except** FumbleFingers  *(or perhaps even more likely,* **apart from***)*

---

TL;DR: In these contexts, the negated form of ***except*** is ***not excepting*** or ***not excepted***. To my mind, it's something of an "erroneous back-formation" to remove ***not*** from either of the "tensed" verb forms to get back to the non-negated sense.

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree with the rule. "Excepting" is similar in meaning to, for instance, "excluding".

Almost no one would think twice about using "excluding" this way:

> Excluding the previous month, sales have increased every month for the past five years.

Likewise, it's correct to use "excepting" in a similar manner:

> Excepting Alice and Bob, who were delayed by bad weather, everyone who responded to the invitation was able to make it to the party.